# Does Xcode build comments code into its binary?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I comment some code in my project and don't want these to be built into my app's binary. 
Does Xcode build comments code into its binary?

```
//Obj-C
//- (void)functionName {
//    
//}

//Swift
//func functionName() {
//
//}
```

Comment: No. Your code (as text) isn't even in the binary.

Comment: Is there an official document?

Comment: FYI - this has nothing to do with Xcode. This is a result of the specific compiler used for the given language you are using.

Comment: I want to be sure if somebody scan or dump my app that these comments will not be detected.

Comment: @ovo To rmaddy's point, this is about LLVM, the compiler behind Xcode. Comments don't get copied into the final binary, but I doubt you'll find an "official document" that states that. For one, there's no mapping between line numbers in source text and line numbers in the binary (heck, there aren't even "lines" in a binary), so it wouldn't even be clear where comments would go. Let alone the fact that the instructions of the code they describe is likely so disfigured and rearranged. If you don't trust us, just build a binary and inspect it yourself.

Comment: To Alexander's point, you can use a hex editor or the command-line `hexdump` or `xxd` commands in Terminal.app to see all the bytes in your binary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Swift: From [The Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) in the “The Swift Programming Language” (emphasis mine):

> Use comments to include nonexecutable text in your code, as a note or reminder to yourself. Comments are **ignored by the Swift compiler** when your code is compiled.

For Objective-C: Objective-C is an extension of C, and the [C 99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) specifies in “5.1.1.2 Translation phases” (emphasis added):

> 3 The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens6) and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. **Each comment is replaced by one space character.** New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.

and in “6.4.9 Comments”:

> 1 Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters /* introduce a comment. **The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the characters */ that terminate it.**
>
> 2 Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters // introduce a comment that includes all multibyte characters up to, but not including, the next new-line character. **The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the terminating new-line character.**

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**:
Every single SDK has a compiler that compiles code into machine language (aka, hexadecimal codes for each of the commands). So, all compilers will ignore comments 100%, so that it can compile codes faster.

In terms of Apple's app, it is bundled such way that in it is packed with all the assets (images, sounds, plist, that are able to be viewed by anybody with the .app file. This is the case where hackers were able to create exactly same app but with slightly different graphics/sounds and resubmit as their own.

Together with those assets, is the BINARY UNIX EXECUTABLE file, which if you open in a notepad, you will see gibberish (machine code cant be read by notepad). Example below is one of my app:
[image]